# How to find if a linux crontab entry fails

Tags: linux, cron, rhel

Our environment is RHEL 5.7. I would like to know if one of the crontab entry in the crontab failes to execute ( even though the entry available in the crontab ), is it getting logged. If so where and which log file. I have gone through the `/var/log/cron` logfile. But it just show only the execution of the crontab entries,crontab edit start,stop etc such as

```
Feb 11 16:03:01 BGRIPD01 crond[3665]: (oracle) CMD (sh 
/home/oracle/cronlogtest.sh > /home/oracle/cronlogtest.log 2>&1)


Feb 11 16:02:04 BGRIPD01 crontab[32690]: (oracle) REPLACE (oracle)


Feb 11 16:02:04 BGRIPD01 crontab[32690]: (oracle) END EDIT (oracle)


Feb 11 16:02:09 BGRIPD01 crontab[1033]: (oracle) LIST (oracle)


Feb 11 16:03:01 BGRIPD01 crond[7883]: (oracle) RELOAD (cron/oracle)
```

Is there any other option to get the failure results and reasons.

I knew that one of the other way is to append the `crontab` entry activity to a logfile like below

```
10 14 * * * sh /home/oracle/cronlogtest.sh > /home/oracle/cronlogtest.log 2>&1
```

But in my scenario I want a single logfile where only the crontab entry failures get logged. Is there any other logfile or other option to log the failures. Kindly help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: You can write a bash script starting the application, and call that script from cron. If starting fails, your script can log it.

Comment: Alright. Let me check whether I can develop a shell script to find out the crontab entry failures.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking too much from CRON.

I have each cron job writing to a log file. It writes begin/end and debug info. They could all write to the same file or not. In my case they write to their own file in a directory for cron logs. I also have some cron jobs which also write their status to a database table.

Once I had trouble understanding why a cron job failed to execute. Our sysadmin said CRON was calling it each day as I had asked. But it wasn't doing what it was supposed to do. After a bit of badgering the sysadmin worked with me on the problem. I had uploaded the cron job in dos format. CRON did what is was supposed to do. I needed to convert the cron job to unix format. I did and everything worked.